# Publish Error Azure Function - event name should have at least 3 parts separated by slash

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, windows-10, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I have recently updated Visual Studio 2019 to Version 16.8.6 and after update I am not able to publish Azure Function to Azure using

> Import Profile

While publishing I am getting below error -

[image]
Please note I have different accounts for Azure & Visual Studio. I have logged in Visual Studio using my abc@test.com while my Azure Subscriptions is xyz@test.com.  I saw few links related to this but it didn't solve my issue. I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in the past, nothing to do with Azure Function. To fix it go to **`File=>Account Settings`** in Visual studio and sign in

Comment: I have logged in Visual Studio using my abc@test.com while my Azure Subscriptions is xyz@test.com.

Comment: You need to use the one which has the access to azure portal

Comment: The Account which has license on VS 2019 is different that one have subscription on Azure Portal

Comment: That's what I'm sayig, when you are deploying change the account profile

Comment: My azure profile doesn't have VS Subscription so when I switch to Azure Profile at time of deployment in VS, I am not able to login in VS since I don't have valid license associated with it.

Comment: i see, you need to have the subscription access

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by updating visual studio version to latest

Answer (score 0):

i tried changing account, restarting, re-creating app service but none of those able to fix it, so i updated VS version to latest then it was resolved.